# An error fetching data on Google sheets via API

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-api

I have a simple project where I have some code that fetches data from a Google sheet and displays it on a simple HTML website as long as the user inputs a "code" obtained through column J of a spreadsheet.

I initially began this with a test spreadsheet where I would create my own code and then view the test information until I was happy. I then tried taking it to the next step where I created a Google form, collected responses, used =arrayformulas to import the collected information into certain columns in a second sheet and used the Google Apps Script to randomly generate character strings that would act as the "code" to trigger every minute for every new row (or essentially every new submission).

This works fine, however, when I try to replace the test sheet with my new final sheet, I run into problems. I've looked at the code and replaced the sheet name, sheet ID and more, however, the codes from column J on my actual sheet don't seem to work, but if I replace the sheet ID to the test one it works fine.

`var spreadsheetUrl = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/my_spreadsheet_link/values/Codes!A1%3AJ?key=my_api_key";`

I've attached my entire code (beware, it's quite messy)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>MESL - Cooldowns</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon_link"
    type="image/x-icon">

  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700;italic&display=swap');

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      font-family: 'Poppins', Arial, sans-serif;
      font-weight: 700;
    }

    .fade-in {
      animation: fade-in 1s ease-in;
    }

    @keyframes fade-in {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }

      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    input[type="text"] {
      font-family: "Poppins", Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #5d6dac65;
      /* Light blue background color */
    }

    .yellow {
      width: 30%;
      background-color: #eebb42;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
      box-shadow: 0 8px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      /* Adjust the box-shadow values to increase the intensity */
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 42px;
    }

    .yellow h1 {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 32px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      /* Adjust the margin-bottom value to your preference */
      margin-top: -10px;
      /* Adjust the margin-bottom value to your preference */
    }

    .yellow input[type="text"] {
      width: calc(100% - 20px);
      /* Updated width */
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 24px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      border: none;
      background-color: transparent;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
      color: #fff;
      outline: none;
      margin-left: -10px;
      /* Added negative margin */
    }

    .yellow input[type="text"]::placeholder {
      color: #fff;
      opacity: 0.7;
      font-family: 'Poppins', Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .blue,
    .links {
      width: 30%;
      height: 510px;
      /* Set a fixed height for the blue box */
      background-color: #5d6dac;
      padding: 20px;
      /* display: flex; */
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: start;
      border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
      overflow-y: auto;

      /* Add overflow-y property to enable scrolling if content exceeds the fixed height */
    }

    .links {
      display: flex;
      align-items: initial;
      width: -webkit-fill-available;
      height: auto;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .link-box {
      height: 67px;
      width: 67px;
      border: 4px solid #fff;
      font-size: 49px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #ffffff;
      margin: 9px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .link-box a {
      color: #ffffff;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* Changing the color of the box itself */
    .link-box:hover {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      color: #5d6dac;
    }

    /* Changing the color of the number inside the box */
    .link-box:hover a {
      color: #5d6dac;
    }

    .blue-box {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .blue-box span {
      display: block;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 24px;
      margin: 5px 0;
      text-align: center;
      padding-left: 20px;
      /* Add your custom padding value here */
    }

    .blue-box span.underline {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .blue-box div:not(:last-child) {
      margin-bottom: -150px;
      /* Adjusted margin-bottom value */
    }

    .blue-box .iframe {
      width: 100%;
      height: 700px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      /* Add your desired margin value here */
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      /* Center horizontally */
      align-items: center;
      /* Center vertically */
    }

    .blue-box a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-bottom: none;
    }

    .blue-box span.iframe {
      margin-top: 20px;
      font-style: italic;
      font-family: 'Poppins', Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .blue-box .gap {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    table {
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    th,
    td {
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: left;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }

    .logo {
      max-width: 30%;
      height: auto;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .iframe {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .bottom-yellow {
      flex-grow: 0;
      width: 30%;
      background-color: #eebb42;
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
      margin-bottom: 42px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      box-shadow: 0 8px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      /* Adjust the box-shadow values to increase the intensity */
    }

    .bottom-yellow p {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 24px;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .bottom-yellow a {
      color: white;
      /* Set the default color to white */
      text-decoration: underline;
      /* Add an underline */
    }

    .bottom-yellow a:hover {
      color: #8398ec;
      /* Change the color to blue on hover */
    }

    .blue::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 12px;
      /* Set the width of the scrollbar */
    }

    .blue::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: #5d6dac;
      /* Change the color of the scrollbar thumb (slider) */
    }

    .blue::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background-color: #5d6dac;
      /* Change the color of the scrollbar track */
    }

    .expand {
      transition: opacity 1s ease;
    }

    .collapse {
      transition: opacity 1s ease;
    }

    .verticle-cener {
      margin: 0 !important;
      position: absolute !important;
      top: 30% !important;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50px !important;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50px !important;
    }

    .blue {
      transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
      height: 510px;
    }

    .collapse {
      height: 0;
    }

    .expand {
      height: auto;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var spreadsheetUrl = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/my_spreadsheet_link/values/Codes!A1%3AJ?key=my_api_key";
      var keywordField = $("#input-field");
      var tableContainer = $("#table-container");
      var blueBox = $(".blue");
      animateCollapse();

      function animateCollapse() {
        var element = document.getElementsByClassName("blue")[0];
        var element1 = document.getElementsByClassName("bottom-yellow")[0];
        var element2 = document.getElementsByClassName("yellow")[0];

        if (element.childNodes.length > 1) {
          element.style.height = element.scrollHeight + "px";
          element.classList.remove("collapse");
          element.classList.add("expand");
          element2.classList.remove("verticle-cener");
          element1.style.display = "block";
          element.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          element.style.height = "0";
          element.classList.remove("expand");
          element2.classList.add("verticle-cener");
          element.classList.add("collapse");
          element1.style.display = "none";
          element.style.display = "none";


        }
      }



      var fetchData = function () {
        $.get(spreadsheetUrl, function (data) {
          var rows = data.values;
          var table = "<table>";
          for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var row = rows[i];
            table += "<tr class='hidden'>";
            for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
              table += "<td>" + row[j] + "</td>";
            }
            table += "</tr>";
          }
          table += "</table>";
          tableContainer.html(table);
        });
      };

      fetchData();

      var performSearch = function () {
        var userInput = keywordField.val();
        var rows = tableContainer.find("tr");
        rows.each(function () {
          var codeCell = $(this).find("td:nth-child(10)");
          var code = codeCell.text();
          if (userInput === code) {
            let link_number = 0;
            $(this).removeClass("hidden");

            blueBox.html("");

            var link_data = "<div class='links'>";
            var columns = $(this).find("td");
            columns.each(function (index) {
              var value = $(this).text();
              if (value !== "") {
                if (index < 3) {
                  let class_name = "";
                  var prefix = "";
                  var link = "";
                  switch (index) {
                    case 0:
                      prefix = "username: ";
                      link = "link" + value;
                      value = "<a href='" + link + "' target='_blank'>" + value + "</a>";
                      break;
                    case 1:
                      prefix = "Reason: ";
                      break;
                    case 2:
                      prefix = "Duration of cooldown: ";
                      break;
                  }
                  if (index < 3) {
                    blueBox.append("<div class='blue-box'><span class='underline fade-in'>" + prefix + "</span><span class='fade-in'>" + value + "</span></div>");

                  } else {
                    blueBox.append("<div class='blue-box'><span>" + prefix + "</span><span>" + value + "</span></div>");
                  }
                } else {
                  if (index === 3) {
                    blueBox.append("<div class='blue-box'><span class='fade-in'><em style='font-style: italic;'>view proof of your cooldown below</em></span></div>");
                  }
                  var link = "";
                  ++link_number;
                  var links_columns = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
                  if (links_columns.includes(index)) {
                    link = "<a href='" + value + "' target='_blank'>" + link_number + "</a>";
                    link_data += "<div class='link-box fade-in'>" + link + "</div>";

                  }
                }
              }
            });
            if (link_data != "<div class='links'>") {
              link_data += "</div>";
            }
            blueBox.append(link_data);
            $(".link-box").on("click", function () {
              window.open($(this).find("a").attr("href"));
            });
          } else {
            $(this).addClass("hidden");

          }
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
          animateCollapse();
        }, 800); // Wait for the transition to complete before hiding the element
      };
      //setup before functions
      var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
      var doneTypingInterval = 15;  //time in ms, 5 seconds for example
      var $input = keywordField;

      //on keyup, start the countdown
      $input.on('keyup', function () {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
      });

      //on keydown, clear the countdown 
      $input.on('keydown', function () {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
      });

      //user is "finished typing," do something
      function doneTyping() {
        performSearch();
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="yellow">
      <img class="logo"
        src="logo_link"
        alt="Logo">
      <h1>View your cooldown - Beta release</h1>
      <input type="text" id="input-field" placeholder="Enter your key">
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="table-container"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="bottom-yellow">
      <p>More support on the <a href="link" target="_blank">MESL discord</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```